# Loop if file exists, go to next iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to search a file in the local directory and if it doesn't exist just to name as in the second block of the if function, and thereon in to iterate and save with the name Rev i (where i is the iteration number 1 to 10), only if i-1 exists. I'm not sure if that makes sense, but I've attached my code (Sorry, it is quite lengthy)

Thanks guys :)

```
DirFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & QuoteNo & " - " & Client & " Rev " & i - 1 & ".docm"
For i = 1 To 10
  If Dir(DirFile) <> "" Then
    With objDoc
      objDoc.Bookmarks("Quote").Select    'To place the Quote Number in the Word Template
      .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "Quote "
      .Application.Selection = QuoteNo & " - Revision " & i
    End With

    With objDoc
      objDoc.Bookmarks("Footer").Select    'To place the Client Name in the Word Template
      .Application.Selection.Find.Text = ""
      .Application.Selection = Client & ": Rev. " & i
    End With

    Worksheets("Dewater - E&Q").UsedRange.Copy
    objDoc.Activate
    objDoc.Application.Run "EQAlign"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    objDoc.Application.Run "PrintLayout"

    objDoc.SaveAs FileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & QuoteNo & " - " & Client & " Rev " & i
  Next i
  Exit For
 Else
   With objDoc
     objDoc.Bookmarks("Quote").Select    'To place the Quote Number in the Word Template
     .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "Quote "
     .Application.Selection = QuoteNo
   End With

   With objDoc
     objDoc.Bookmarks("Footer").Select    'To place the Client Name in the Word Template
     .Application.Selection.Find.Text = ""
     .Application.Selection = Client
   End With

   Worksheets("Dewater - E&Q").UsedRange.Copy
   objDoc.Activate
   objDoc.Application.Run "EQAlign"
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   objDoc.Application.Run "PrintLayout"

   objDoc.SaveAs FileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & QuoteNo & " - " & Client
 End If
```

Comment: Can you tell what is working already in this code, and what functionality you want to add? Does all of this code is relevant for solving your problem?

Comment: Using code indentation, you can see that your For and IF structure are not correct, this code won't even compile...that is problem #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only thing that differentiates the `If` block from the `Else` block is the revision number, and that is based on whether or not you find a matching file name. Instead of trying to do everything at once, break it into 2 separate tasks - first find the revision, *then* do everything else based on what revision number you found. This avoids repeating the majority of the code twice (there are exactly 2 lines that are different other than the file name).

I'd also replace the `For` loop with a `Do Until` loop. This matches the semantics of what you are doing better and makes the code more readable as to its intent.  It also combines the test for exiting the loop into the ***loop itself***, so you don't need to test for an exit condition separately:

```
'Find a unique revision\file name.
Dim revision As Long
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DirFile = QuoteNo & " - " & Client & ".docm"
    Do Until Not .FileExists(.BuildPath(ActiveWorkbook.Path, DirFile))
        revision = revision + 1
        DirFile = QuoteNo & " - " & Client & " Rev " & revision & ".docm"
    Loop
Next

With objDoc
    objDoc.Bookmarks("Quote").Select 'To place the Quote Number in the Word Template
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "Quote "
    'This is based on the revision found above.
    If revision = 0 Then
        .Application.Selection = QuoteNo
    Else
        .Application.Selection = QuoteNo & " - Revision " & revision
    End If
End With

With objDoc
    objDoc.Bookmarks("Footer").Select 'To place the Client Name in the Word Template
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = ""
    'This is based on the revision found above.
    If revision = 0 Then
        .Application.Selection = Client
    Else
        .Application.Selection = Client & ": Rev. " & revision
    End If
End With

Worksheets("Dewater - E&Q").UsedRange.Copy
objDoc.Activate
objDoc.Application.Run "EQAlign"
Application.CutCopyMode = False

objDoc.Application.Run "PrintLayout"
objDoc.SaveAs DirFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get a functionality similar to `break` in other java.
VBA does not provide break as any inbuilt keyword.
However there is a smart workaround that I used to use in my projects. Here is how it works.

--Without break

```
for i = 0 to x
 statement 1
 statement 2
 statement 3
next
```

In above code suppose you want to go to next iteration after statement 2, you wont be able to.
But try this

```
for i = 0 to x
    for i = 1 to 1
     statement 1
     statement 2
     '---if you need to break here, just do exit for and you will be out of inner loop (from 1 to 1)
     exit for
     statement 3
    next
   next
```

Using above method, by employing 1 to 1 for loop, you will be able to exit the inner loop and hence effectively going to the next iteration of the main loop, and thus replicating the break keyword.

Let me know if this is what you needed.